# Click event not registered in IE, jQuery on div (jsfiddle)

Tags: jquery, html, css, events

I've got html that looks like this:

```
<h3>Sample</h3>
<div class="skjemaHjelp" id="sample"><div><h3>3</h3><p>Content goes here</p></div></div>
<input type="text"  class="inputWide" name="formSample" id="formSample" value="" />
```

The class skjemaHjelp is posisioned on the right side of the input-field and styled with a help-icon. The content within .skjemaHjelp div is hidden.

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$('.skjemaHjelp, .skjemaHjelpU').click(function () {
alert('debug');
}):
```

The alert-box appears in every browser, except IE. For some reason the event does not fire. I have no idea why. Are there any workarounds?

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wJEPV/11/

Thomas

Comment: You should show us using a jsfiddle so we can see your problem happening and test possible solutions

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wJEPV/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're testing with IE lower than version 9 (or IE9 in a different Document Mode), the only problem with your jsFiddle is that the `console` object is not defined.

If you remove `console.log('loaded');`, it works in all versions of IE.

In earlier versions of IE, the `console` object is only defined when you open the Developer Tools (hit F12).

Alternatively, you can add something like this to make it always safe to use `console.*`:

```
// make it safe to use console.log always
(function(b){function c(){}for(var d="assert,clear,count,debug,dir,dirxml,error,exception,firebug,group,groupCollapsed,groupEnd,info,log,memoryProfile,memoryProfileEnd,profile,profileEnd,table,time,timeEnd,timeStamp,trace,warn".split(","),a;a=d.pop();){b[a]=b[a]||c}})((function(){try
{console.log();return window.console;}catch(err){return window.console={};}})());
```

(snippet taken from http://html5boilerplate.com/)

Comment: Removing the console.log did it. Thank you so much. Weird that it only ruined this function, the picture-shuffler worked with no problems. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a  `tabindex="0"` property to your div. This will make it fire the `click` event.